# Mobius transformation with exactly one fixed point

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $T$ be a mobius transformation with exactly one fixed point on $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$.  What form does $T$ take? Find a fomrula for $T^n(z)$. What happens to $T^n(z)$ as $n \to \infty$.

## Attempt

(we will assume $w \neq \infty$ since this case I covered already). If we examine a generic Mobius transformation with exactly one fixed point then we will have

$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=z$$

which is solvable by the quadratic equation

$$\frac{a-d \pm \sqrt{(d-a)^2-4cb}}{2c}$$

Since there is only one fixed point this corresponds to the discrimanant being $0$ and so we have the following conditions

\begin{align*}
                        (d-a)^2-4cb&=0\\
                        \frac{a-d}{2c}&=z
                    \end{align*}

If $z=0$ then we have $b=0$ and our transformation is of the form

$$\frac{az}{cz+d}$$ . . .

## confusion

Frome here the algebra seems to get a bit nasty and I'm not convinced I'm not on the right track going in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find that if the only fixed point on the Riemann sphere is $\infty$ then our transformation takes the form $T(z)=z+b$. Now, if we want to consider an arbitrary fixed point, call it $w$, then we can look at a new transformation $S$ which exchanges $w$ and $\infty$.

Now, we may write our new transformation which fixes $w$, $T_w$, as follows

$$T_w=S^{-1}TS$$

Even if $S$ fixes some points $T$ will unfix them, all but $w$ that is which will be fixed because of $T$. To find a transformation which exchanges $\infty$ and $w$ we consider

$$S=\frac{1}{z-w}$$

which is indeed a Mobius transformation making the above a composition of Mobius transformations and, thus, a Mobius transformation.

Answer (score 5):

After conjugating by an appropriate transformation $S$, you can assume that the fixed point is $\infty$. Then what form does $T$ take?